# Как можно сжать код при этом сохранить читабельность

Tags: swift, инспекция-кода, swift4

Как сделать этот Код *компактней* и какие советы по Коду вы можете дать?

```
//Программа решающая квадратные неравенства
import Foundation

var 
values: Array<Double> = [0, -1, 8, 0],
roots: Array<Double> = [0],
discriminant: Double = 0,
cell: Int = 0,
sign: Int = 1

discriminant = pow(values[2], 2) - 4 * values[1] * values[3]
if discriminant > 0 {
    roots.append((-values[2] + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * values[1]))
    roots.append((-values[2] - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * values[1]))
} else {
    roots.append((-values[2]) / (2 * values[1]))
}

if values[1] > 0 && discriminant > 0 {
    cell = 1
} else if values[1] > 0 && discriminant == 0 {
    cell = 2
} else if values[1] > 0 &&  discriminant < 0 {
    cell = 3
} else if values[1] < 0 && discriminant > 0 {
    cell = 4
} else if values[1] < 0 && discriminant == 0 {
    cell = 5
} else if values[1] < 0 && discriminant < 0 {
    cell = 6
}

if sign == 1 && cell == 1 || sign == 2 && cell == 4 {
print("(-Бесконечность; \(roots[2])) (\(roots[1]); +Бесконечность)")
 } else if sign == 1 && cell == 4 || sign == 2 && cell == 1 {
    print("(\(roots[2]); \(roots[1]))")
 } else if sign == 3 && cell == 1 || sign == 4 && cell == 4 {
    print("(-Бесконечность; \(roots[2])] [\(roots[1]); +Бесконечность)")
 } else if sign == 3 && cell == 4 || sign == 4 && cell == 1 {
    print("[\(roots[2]); \(roots[1])]")
 } else if sign == 1 && cell == 2 || sign == 2 && cell == 5 {
    print("(-Бесконечность; \(roots[3])) (\(roots[3]); +Бесконечность)")
 } else if sign == 3 && cell == 5 || sign == 4 && cell == 2 {
    print("\(roots[3])")
 } else if sign == 1 && cell == 3 || sign == 2 && cell == 6 || sign == 3 && cell == 2 || sign == 3 && cell == 3 || sign == 4 || cell == 5 || sign == 4 && cell == 5 {
    print("(-Бесконечность; +Бесконечность)")
} else if sign == 1 && cell == 5 || sign == 1 && cell == 6 || sign == 2 || cell == 2 || sign == 2 && cell == 3 || sign == 3 && cell == 6 || sign == 4 && cell == 3 {
    print("Нет решений")
}
```

Comment: Но зачем? Чисто теоретический интерес?

Comment: @Yaant я хочу научиться писать красивый и читабельный код, странно, кто не хочет?

Comment: Так одно дело красивый, другое дело компактный, это ж совсем разные вещи.

Comment: @Yaant для меня красота заключается в компактности, думаю это нормально что у нас разное видение красоты :/

Comment: Что до советов, то, например, у Вас `sign` равен 1, и нигде не меняется, поэтому все условия с проверкой `sign` можно сильно упростить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше сделать по другому, решил Я, код вроде стал меньше и более читабельным *(На мой взгляд)*

```
import Foundation
func solutionOfQuadraticInequalities(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double, sign: Int) -> String {//Решение квадратных неравенств
    if (sign > 4) || (sign < 0) || (a == 0) { return "Hello, world!" }//Если а равен 0 или пользователь ввёл значение не от 1 до 4, то приложение пишет Hello, World!
    enum Signs: String {
        case infinity = "\u{221e}"//Знак бесконечности
        case association = "\u{222a}"//Знак объединения
    }
    var D = pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c)//Нахождение дискриминанта
    var x1 = (-b + sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)//Первый корень или единственный корень
    var cell: Int?//Ячейка 1-6
    if (D > 0) {
        var x2 = (-b - sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)//Второй корень
        if (a > 0) { cell = 1 }
        else if (a < 0) { cell = 4 }
        if (cell == 1 && sign == 1) || (cell == 4 && sign == 2) {
            return "(-\(Signs.infinity); \(x2)) \(Signs.association) (\(x1); +\(Signs.infinity))"
        } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 2) || (cell == 4 && sign == 1) {
            return "(\(x2); \(x1))"
        } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 3) || (cell == 4 && sign == 4) {
            return "(-\(Signs.infinity); \(x2)] \(Signs.association) [\(x1); +\(Signs.infinity))"
        } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 4) || (cell == 4 && sign == 3) {
            return "[\(x2); \(x1)]"
        }
    } else {
        if (D == 0) {
            if (a > 0) { cell = 2 }
            else if (a < 0) { cell = 5}
        } else if (D < 0) {
            if (a > 0) { cell = 3 }
            else if (a < 0) { cell = 6 }
        }
        if (cell == 2 && sign == 1) || (cell == 5 && sign == 2) {
            return "(-\(Signs.infinity); \(x1)) \(Signs.association) (\(x1); +\(Signs.infinity))"
        } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 2) || (cell == 5 && sign == 1) || (cell == 3 && sign == 2 || sign == 4) || (cell == 6 && sign == 1 || sign == 3) {
            return "Нет решения"
        } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 3) || (cell == 5 && sign == 4) || (cell == 3 && sign == 1 || sign == 3) || (cell == 6 && sign == 2 || sign == 4) {
            return "(-\(Signs.infinity); +\(Signs.infinity))"
        } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 4) || (cell == 5 && sign == 3) {
            return "\(x1)"
        }
    }
    return "Something went wrong!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет смысла про три раза проверять `values[1]` на больше/меньше 0. Можно объединить ветки с одинаковыми условиями:

```
if values[1] > 0 {
   if discriminant > 0 { cell = 1 } 
   else if discriminant == 0 { cell = 2 } 
   else { cell = 3 }
} else if values[1] < 0 {
   if discriminant > 0 { cell = 4 } 
   else if discriminant == 0 { cell = 5 } 
   else { cell = 6 }
}
```

Второго монстра наверняка тоже можно упростить, если есть готовая табличка с исходами.